# Shopify CLI page size is too high?

Tags: next.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am working on an shopify app, I am using the shopify app CLI as recommended by Shopify to create and serve the app. What I am finding is page sizes for each Page is too high. I am attaching a screenshot for reference.

[image]

This is highly annoying and is making the development very slow. Is this expected, am I missing something, are there any configurations that should be updated.

Continuing further investigation, I created a simple node app from shopify cli, no personal code added, just plain barebone app created by shopify cli, on serving this app in my dev store, I still get heavy page sizes causing time delay to load page (page size is bloated up time to render this empty page is 40~secs and page size is 5.78mb)

[image]

There is no documentation on any configuration changes that we need to tweek.

I downloaded these heavy page files to check what is in it, the webpack is somehow bundling all my components in my app js and index js files (repeatedly), its bundling all this unnecessary files causing each page file to bloat up, it would be really helpful if someone from shopify or may be nextjs can point out the configurations I need to update, to change this behaviour.

Comment: Maybe you are included a lot of bloatware in your App? Where do you think the bloat is coming from? Obviously you are in control of what you render, in the sense that you decide what to render in your source code. Without you listing that, how is anyone supposed to help you.

Comment: Hi @DavidLazar, please check my question update.

Comment: have you solved it? Let me know, facing same issue